# How can I convert string into lines

Tags: android

In the website, the user is sending data from `textarea` as multi lines, like:

```
Actions required:
- actin 1: xxx
- action 2: yyy
additional notes
```

These data is sent as `String` to the server, which send it to the Android app.

In android, while displaying this data in `textview` it appeared as single line, not multiple lines, like:

```
Actions required: - actin 1: xxx - action 2: yyy additional notes
```

How can I fix it, so that the data is displayed in the Android textarea as multiple lines the same way it was entered in the website!

Comment: could you maybe print or add a breakpoint on the exact location you receive this string from the server ?

Comment: Without any tag or delimiter, new line cannot be distinguished. So can you post the exact string data which you are getting from server from log?

Comment: Have a look to the text if you found /CR /LF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.

One way is to send the text to server as `html` text to make it able to detect the new line "\n", i.e:

```
sendToCloud(Html.toHtml(edittext.getText()))
// and set it as:
String multilineText = Html.fromHtml(textFromCloud);
```

OR simply you can split the text as it to get actions as array, i.e:

`String[] actions = textFromCloud.split("-"); // will split to string of arrays start after "-"`

Comment: Split part will not give the desired result

Comment: @AliAhsan What will it give then!?

Comment: @AliAhsan not correct, output will be ["Actions required: ", "actin 1: xxx ", "action 2: yyy additional notes"]

Comment: @AliAhsan However one solution should work correctly with OP.

Comment: Agree but this is not what he want

Comment: OP never talks about sending anything to the server, he says it is done on a website and then received on the app. your sending method is therefore irrelevant, but i agree he should try parsing it from html